# How to write multiple statements in one if block in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm writing a function in clojure, that takes in 2 arguments (both are lists), and iterates over vehicles by recursion, until the vehicle list becomes empty. The function is like:

```
(defn v [vehicles locs]
    (if (= (count vehicles) 0)
        nil
        (if (> (count vehicles) 0)
            (split-at 1 locs)
            (v (rest vehicles) (rest locs))
        ))
    )
```

So, if I give the input as `(v '(v1 v2 v3) '([1 2] [2 3] [4 2] [5 3]))`, then I want the output as `[([1 2]) ([3 4]) ([5 6] [6 7])]`. I know that the statement `(v (rest vehicles) (rest locs))` is not executing because it's taking it in the else case i.e., when count(vehicles) not > 0. I want to know how can I make this statement be executed in the same if block, i.e., in `(if (> (count vehicles) 0)`

Comment: Take a look at [`when`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when).

Comment: @Mark Thanks! Is there something like break? Because while iterating in the end it reaches (if (= (count vehicles) 0) and then prints nil only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```
(defn v [vehicles locs]
  (if (seq (rest vehicles))
    (concat  [[(first locs)]] (v (rest vehicles) (rest locs)))
    [locs]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I could get the output as ((v1 [1 2]) (v2 [0 2] [3 2])), if I give the input: (v '(v1 v2) '([1 2] [0 2] [3 2]))?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using recursion and need to return some result of execution there is good approach to accumulate all of your recursion step's results in one holder variable. Here `result` is such a holder:

```
(defn v [vehicles locs]
  (if (empty? vehicles)
    nil
    (loop [result [] vs vehicles ls locs]
      (if (= 1 (count vs))
        (conj result ls)
        (recur (conj result (first ls)) (rest vs) (rest ls))))))
```

It works like this:

```
(v '(v1 v2 v3) '([1 2] [2 3] [4 2] [5 3]))
=> [[1 2] [2 3] ([4 2] [5 3])]
```

If you really need to wrap location one-element vectors (but actually it seems like a strange requirement) then try the following:

```
(defn v [vehicles locs]
  (if (empty? vehicles)
    nil
    (loop [result [] vs vehicles ls locs]
      (if (= 1 (count vs))
        (conj result ls)
        (recur (conj result (list (first ls))) (rest vs) (rest ls))))))
```

Comment: No need for an accumulator in a very simple case like this one, see my answer. It could be made lazy trivially too.

Answer (score 1):

You can write multiple statements in `if` branches with a `do` form:

```
(if (= 1 (count vs))
  (do
    (conj result ls)
    (recur (conj result (first ls)) (rest vs) (rest ls)))
  :else)
```

If you don't need `else` branch it's convenient to use `when` macro:

```
(when (= 1 (count vs))
  (conj result ls)
  (recur (conj result (first ls)) (rest vs) (rest ls)))
```